# Required value from bean doesn't change back to "false"

Tags: validation, jsf, required

Thank you for your help some hours ago!
Now, I face a new problem... :(

The field, which should be required if a special radio button is selected cannot change back to "required=false" if the radio button is changed again.
The error message, that the field cannot be empty is shown.

Here is my code:

```
Bean method:

public void required(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    if (test.isRadioButton()) {
        requirement = true;
    } else {
         requirement = false;
    }
}

----

xhtml:

<h:panelGroup id="buttons" layout="block" styleClass="buttonAbstand" >
    <p:selectOneRadio id="radio" value="#{bean.test.radioButton}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{i18n['error.response']}" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{true}" itemLabel="#{i18n['common.ja']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{false}" itemLabel="#{i18n['common.nein']}" />
        <f:ajax execute="panel1" listener="#{bean.required}" render="panel1" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="panel1" >
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.requirement}" >
        <br />
        <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['input']}" styleClass="labelFont" />      
        <br />
        <p:inputText id="inputText" value="#{bean.test.input}" styleClass="text" required="#{bean.requirement}" requiredMessage="#{i18n['error.input']}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

My bean has these annotations:
    @Service
    @ViewScoped
    @Getter
    @Setter.

I would be very glad if you could help me!
Best wishes!

Comment: Just use `requirement = test.isRadioButton()` - you really don't need the `if` in this case. 

Besides that, your problem might be that you're not updating your form (if this is a form) after calling your function, or you're not setting the `isRadioButton()` properly, can we see the code involving that radiobutton?

Comment: Where and when **should** it be updated? You do not do that anywhere in the code above, so all is normal!!!. Please learn on creating a [mcve]

Comment: I added the part with the radio buttons to the code-snippet.

Comment: Why are you explicitly executing the panel1 during toggling if you actually want to skip its execution?

Comment: If the radio button "true" is selected, the panel1 should be rendered an the inputText should be required. Am I missing something? Can I realise this in an other way?

Comment: Regarding the execute and render attributes, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes